# typecast userdefaults into Int() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Here is set price to user default (`LoggedInUserSave` is reference to `UserDefault`):

```
let currentValue = Int(sender.value)
LblPriceValue.text = "\(currentValue)"
Price = "0," + String(describing: currentValue)
LoggedInUserSave.set(Price, forKey: "PriceFilter")
```

I need use `price` value as `Int`. I am using this code to convert the `price` to `int`:

```
p = LoggedInUserSave.value(forKey: "PriceFilter") as! String
Price : Int = Int(p)!
```

While doing this thing getting nil value.

Comment: Sorry, what is `Price : Int = Int(p)!`? I can't even get that to compile.

Comment: Price is just variable to store the value of p

Comment: Fine, but I'm talking about that syntax. I don't know what it means, and it won't compile. You could get better quality help if you posted the actual code you're using.

Comment: Price : Int = Int(p)!

Comment: That's not valid Swift code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several anomalies (excluding wrong use of naming convention of-course) in your code as I can notice, this line (when setting value) depicts var `Price` is of kind `String`

```
Price = "0," + String(describing: currentValue)
```

Where as here (while receiving value) you set indicate `Price` as `integer`.

Now so solve your problem make sure:

- `sender.value` is not nil and only contain numeric characters (otherwise type cast will not be successful)
- Now while saving you are setting it like `"0," + String(describing: currentValue)` which makes is `string` literal that can not be converted into `Int` again.

This will be more appropriate way to achieve what you are trying:

```
    if let i = sender.value as? Int {
        self.lbl.text = "\(i)"
        UserDefaults.standard.set(i, forKey: "Key")
    }
```

_

```
    //..
    if let i : Int = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key") {
        //do what you want to do with stored value
    }
```

Comment: it giving error like this Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' (0x10d978d60) to 'NSNumber' (0x10e94d4a8).

Comment: Do not use the `value(forKey:)` method to read a value from UserDefaults. To get an `Int`, use `integer(forKey:)`.

Comment: `integer(forKey:)` does not return an optional.